# How to Do Jenkins Save/Apply event from script

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl, jenkins-api

I am using this https://python-jenkins.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ python Jenkins API to create a job from XML config. Everything working fine except the webhook for Bitbucket server. I need to  hit save/apply button at least once to activate the Webhook. Is there any way to call this Save/apply event through any script or API?
It would be a great help if anyone can suggest a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Problem is resolved with the latest update of Jenkins - Bitbucket server integration Plug-in